# Marquee for Xamarin.Forms IOS

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin-studio

I have a StackLayout(View) inside of which I am having Image and Label aligned Horizontally (refer screenshot below). The Label should have a Marquee property. For that, we are using animation on the Label (using TranslateTo) and giving new X-position on tap gesture, when we click on the label the label starts moving right to left as Marquee, but it is overlapping the image. Is there any way to implement it in Xamarin.Forms IOS? so Marquee Label won't overlap the Image.[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use RaiseChild(imageview) from the StackLayout to raise the Image and start the animation of Label TranslateTo(); This should make the appearance as label is moving below the image. To even change visibility of the label once the Label-X has reached ImageView-X for which you need to handle the PropertyChanged event of Label or use a behavior to determine the X value of the label.

Comment: StackLayout is  inside List so I can't use raiseChild on it